# Github pages custom domain automatic redirects not working with HTTPS version

Tags: dns, web-hosting, github

I'm using github-pages to host my website [www.prahladyeri.com](http://www.prahladyeri.com). In my github-pages repo, I've configured `CNAME` file to point towards `www.prahladyeri.com`.

Now, as per [these docs](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain-and-www-subdomain/), the transition should seamlessly happen from `www` to `non-www` versions. For example http://prahladyeri.com should redirect to http://www.prahladyeri.com which happens perfectly!

However, this redirection is not happening for HTTPS version of the website. For example, https://prahladyeri.com is not redirecting to https://www.prahladyeri.com.

As a result, non-www users of my website who came in the HTTPS mode are landed nowhere (the browser just keeps on spinning).

Is there any way to fix this so that the redirect works with the HTTPS version of the site too? I'm using the Cloudflare flexi SSL for implementing HTTPS if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently now way to fix that, because GitHub Pages currently don't support HTTPS for custom domains.

As you are using Cloudflare, you need to check whether you can configure such redirect in Cloudflare.